# Consolidating two websites into one, but migrated images not appearing in Image Library

Tags: images, media-library, migration

I am consolidating two websites (which are on the same server) into one.  I copied the images from one website's directory to the other using rsync.

`rsync -av /srv/www/site1/wp-content/uploads/ /srv/www/site2/wp-content/uploads/`

The images appear in the target directory and file permissions and ownerships are fine.

But the images are not appearing in the Media Library and there is no way to link to these images as Featured Images in Jigoshop product items.

Why are these migrated images not appearing in the Media Library?  Is there a way to force WordPress to search the library for new images?

Comment: How did you sync the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when you upload an image via the admin, it's metadata is added to the database, and that's how you can search through them in the media library etc. If you upload images via ftp then they won't appear in the DB so won't show up in the admin area.

Use a plugin such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-from-ftp/ which will let you loop through every image and add them to the DB if they don't exist already.